# Spring Boot CsvMapper bean causes an error when returning a ResponseEntity created with a Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application, I have a CsvMapper that is injected into a Service class. This CsvMapper is defined as a bean in a Config file.

In my Controller, when I return a ResponseEntity that was created by passing in a HashMap, the stack trace displays these errors.

```
    w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Unrecognized column 'message': known columns: ]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMappingException: Unrecognized column 'message': known columns: ] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["message"])]

    w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Unrecognized column 'timestamp': known columns: ]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMappingException: Unrecognized column 'timestamp': known columns: ] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["timestamp"])]
```

Here is a brief layout of these files.

**CsvParserService**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public final class CsvParserService {

    private CsvMapper csvMapper;
    // TODO: This injection causes a problem when creating a ResponseEntity(Map,...). Investigate why this is happening
    public CsvParserService(@Qualifier("myCsvMapper") CsvMapper myCsvMapper) {
        this.csvMapper =  myCsvMapper;
    }

    public <T> List<T> parseCsvFile(Class<T> modelClass, MultipartFile csvFile, boolean ifHeader) throws IOException {
        // create inputStream of the scorecard CSV file
        InputStream fileStream = new BufferedInputStream(csvFile.getInputStream());
        CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper
                .typedSchemaFor(modelClass)
                .withUseHeader(ifHeader)  // this should be configured applied based on the queryParameter value in the PostRequest
                .withColumnSeparator(',')
                .sortedBy("timestamp", "productName", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k");

        MappingIterator<T> iterator = csvMapper
                .readerWithTypedSchemaFor(modelClass)
                .with(csvSchema)
                .readValues(fileStream);
        return iterator.readAll();
    }
```

**The Config file where the bean is defined**

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean(name="myCsvMapper")
    public CsvMapper myCsvMapper(DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter) {
        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        configureDateTimeDeSerialization(javaTimeModule, dateTimeFormatter);
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        csvMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
        return csvMapper;
    }

    private void configureDateTimeDeSerialization(JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule, DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter) {

        // Instant customizations
        javaTimeModule.addSerializer(Instant.class, new JsonSerializer<>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(Instant value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
                gen.writeString(dateTimeFormatter.format(value));
            }
        });
        javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(Instant.class, new JsonDeserializer<>() {
            @Override
            public Instant deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                return dateTimeFormatter.parse(p.getText(), Instant::from);
            }
        });

        // Instant customizations for map keys
        javaTimeModule.addKeySerializer(Instant.class, new JsonSerializer<>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(Instant value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
                gen.writeFieldName(dateTimeFormatter.format(value));
            }
        });
        javaTimeModule.addKeyDeserializer(Instant.class, new KeyDeserializer() {
            @Override
            public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
                return dateTimeFormatter.parse(key, Instant::from);
            }
        });
    }
```

The **controller** where the error occurs on the line with "return new..."

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ScorecardSummaryController {

@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(value = {"/csvmapper"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> getProducts() {

    // some services calls
     Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     map.put("message", "Some message");
     map.put("status", "Ok");
     return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK); // error occurs after this line
    }
}
```

My suspicion is that the CsvMapper bean has become sort of default mapper for the application? But I'm not sure how that happens or why it occurs when creating a ResponseEntity by passing in a HashMap. If I create the ResponseEntity in an alternative way such as
`return new ResponseEntity<String>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);` 
, it will not return any error. If I write code in the @Bean definition to ignore errors of columns unknown, the application does not return anything when I hit the API Endpoint".